# Why is a Git post-commit hook on non-interactive rebase not run?

Tags: git, git-rebase, post-commit-hook, non-interactive

Given an arbitrary, executable Git post-commit hook it is not run during a non-interactive rebase, neither with `rebase --force-rebase` nor with `rebase --no-ff` which is a synonym for the former in non-interactive mode according to the GIT-REBASE(1) Manpage.

But by doing an interactive rebase with `rebase --interactive --no-ff` the very same Git hook is run on post-commit.

Can someone explain the rationale behind this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

> But by doing an interactive rebase with `rebase --interactive --no-ff`, the very same Git hook is run on `post-commit`.

Actually, the `post-commit` hook is *not* run on an interactive rebase since Git 2.17+ (Q4 2017)

It is only run *again* (on `git rebase -i`) with Git 2.25+ (Q1 2020): "`rebase -i`" ceased to run the `post-commit` hook by mistake in an earlier update, which has been corrected.

See [commit 4627bc7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4627bc777e9ade5e3a85d6b8e8630fc4b6e2f8f6), [commit 49697cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49697cb72122cf84b44111124821c9a4bcba3ab6), [commit 12bb7a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12bb7a540a39746fd6f62e4d5ffd016a2178bcf7), [commit 6a619ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a619ca03ce82988f2039ecdfd3565d54aa4d9ed), [commit b2dbacb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2dbacbddfc40e9715d928dafe3256bb56d91dde), [commit 88a92b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88a92b6c7372756c862e409a74a22e1ec660b76a) (15 Oct 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5c8c0a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c8c0a0d78b0e0ee50ba13823f0cfbee05334461), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4627bc777e9ade5e3a85d6b8e8630fc4b6e2f8f6): run `post-commit` hook
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
>
> Prior to [commit 356ee4659b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/356ee4659bb551cd9464b317d691827276752c2d) ("`sequencer`: try to commit without forking 'git commit'", 2017-11-24, Git v2.17.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1772ad1125a6f8a5473d73bbd17162bb20ebd825) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2e45c695d09f6a31ce09347ae0a5d2cdfe9dd4e)) the sequencer would always run the `post-commit` hook after each pick or revert as it forked `git commit` to create the commit.
>
> The conversion to committing without forking `git commit` omitted to call the `post-commit` hook after creating the commit.

Comment: Is there any alternative to bypass `rebase -i` running the `post-commit` hooks?

Comment: @mochadwi If you mean "avoid running the post-commit hook after an interactive rebase", then no, with recent Git version, that does not seem possible (looking at the source code https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c8c0a0d78b0e0ee50ba13823f0cfbee05334461)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

> --no-ff With --interactive, cherry-pick all rebased commits instead of fast-forwarding over the unchanged ones. This ensures that the entire
>   history of the rebased branch is composed of new commits.
>
> Without --interactive, this is a synonym for --force-rebase.
>
> You may find this helpful after reverting a topic branch merge, as
>   this option recreates the topic branch with fresh commits so it can be
>   remerged successfully without needing to "revert the reversion" (see
>   the revert-a-faulty-merge How-To for details).

Cherry pick creates new commits, and git post-commit hook runs after new commit is created, right?

From: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

DESCRIPTION
Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each. This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

Is that clear?

Comment: So, how does that affect the commit hook? Please explain.

Comment: I think this explains why the hook *does* trigger, but you didn't explain why the hook might *not* trigger.